# How do I fully delete an Azure Function workspace in VS Code?

Tags: azure, visual-studio-code, azure-functions

I am dipping my toes into my first azure function development using VS Code. From the Azure extension, I used the "Create Function..." button in the "Workspace" panel to create a python function.

[image: Create Function button]

The Azure tools extensions did lots of things in the background during the process, like setting up a new virtual environment fed by a "requirements.txt", and honestly, I don't know what all else.

Well, long story short, I want to delete the function completely and try again. Perhaps ignorantly, to delete it, I simply deleted the folder within which I created the function. I have double and triple checked, the folder is most certainly gone. However, when I look at "workspaces" in my Azure tab, the "Local Project" that was created when I made the function persists, and points to the directory that no longer exists.

[image: Local Project within Workspace]

As you can see, there are no functions within the project, but the project itself persists. When I try to create a new function with the "Create Function" button, as before, I get the simple error message: "The "requirements.txt" file could not be found."

[image: requirements.txt error]

It seems to me that the Azure tool is attempting to create a new function *within* the old Project, but when it looks for a "requirements.txt" file to help it interface with it, it can't find it (as I deleted it), and bails. Perhaps I'm wrong, though.

How can I well and truly delete the "Local Project" that was created initially to house my first function within VS Code?

When I manually deleted the directory where the "Local Project" in my Azure Workspace tab is pointing to (using windows explorer), I expected the "Local Project" within "Workspace" to go away.

When I attempt to create a new function, I expected the Azure tool to identify the lack of all virtual environment infrastructure, and hence to create a new one, or perhaps give me some error more informative than "The requirements.txt file could not be found."

I have tried using "git reset HEAD --hard" on the repo where the folder I created for the function lives without any luck.

I have searched google to no avail thus far as to how to delete this "Local Project", whatever it is.

Answer (score 0):

> In VS Code, navigate to the folder where the function apps are [located](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FWIBn.png) and [delete](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YnT1c.png) them. Make sure that the folder is not open in VS Code, as that could cause issues.

[image]

- The `requirements.txt` contains

[image]

- [Install](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B2fZJ.png) the   [Azure Functions Core Tools](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-run-local?tabs=v4%2Cwindows%2Ccsharp%2Cportal%2Cbash#install-the-azure-functions-core-tools)
- [Workspace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pqQHu.png)>>[Create function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4SN3M.png) >>[Select the folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zjdsj.png)>>[python](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j3x5e.png)>>[select Interpeter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ia7YT.png) >>[select the Trigger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mGZAA.png)>>[Trigger name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1B1yn.png)>>[Authorization Level](https://i.stack.imgur.com/547Yt.png)

[image]

- Select the terminal, next to the path of the folder and type  `func host start` to run

[image]

[image]

Comment: I have done as you suggest and deleted the folder with the function app contents, as I say in the post. However, this does not delete the "Local Project" in the workspace. I cannot create a new function while VS Code looks for a requirements.txt that is deleted.

Comment: Hello @HelpfulAvocado the Azure function app in Respective [folder](https://i.imgur.com/M6BKeIH.png) in the [respective path](https://i.imgur.com/Tdzt2Cz.png) negative to [your path](https://i.imgur.com/e1o8Tg6.png) and the file related to the Function Make sure that the folder is not open in VS Code. open the [visual studio](https://i.imgur.com/gJwOHbA.png). If you create the function again it will create Local Project

Comment: Hello, @HelpfulAvocado I Created the Azure function from step two